How can I access the administrator password as a guest account? I don't want to reset the password
My husband put an administrator password. If I try to download, it wants me to enter his password but I don't know it. He doesn't like it that I download things (it's his computer but I use it more). I downloaded a software with no issues but part of the download wants access and again, I don't know his password. Anyone know if I can access his password? I've tried net user administrator and the actual password doesn't show up.

You need to take it up with your husband - there's no legal method for doing that.

There is no solution to this problem without the password.

You could try creating a new net user for your local computer with a terminal and then assigning administrative privileges to it, unless your husband has disabled cmd too, at which point you’d need to remove the ‘group’ policy implementations he has set with a third party tool. However, I strongly recommend just having a chat with your husband, unless this isn’t an option.

You can ask him to deploy Windows Sandbox for your experiments with software or some other free hypervisor (Hyper-V or Oracle Virtualbox).
If you need to install some application and its installer is requiring administrator privileges, you can try to cheat it with RUNASINVOKER compatibility flag. Simply create shortcut with this command-line and launch it:
cmd.exe /c "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker && <installer-filename-here.exe>"
Additional ways of doing it are provided by Nir Sofer here
Some installers will check for administrator privileges and will elevate itself anyway, but some will allow installation to user profile if elevation request is denied. Just don't forget to install to user-writable location.
So, here's another way: use some system-level sandbox, like Sandboxie. It can be easily configured to trick installer that it runs as administrator and software would not be able to break OS.
Another shady way is to try stealing user credentials from memory - Mimikatz is a nightmare for system administrators, but your husband could enable Credential Guard to leverage hardware virtualization to protect passwords in memory. Also, I'm sure it's already flagged as malicious by your antivirus.

No, there is not a known easy way to extract the password so you could know it.  If there were, then people would be having their passwords compromised so often that there would be no usefulness for having any sort of secret password.
What could be done is for you to have your own, separate Administrator-level password.  If you can get the computer to boot/start your own code, then you could create a new account, set your own desired password to it, make sure that account has Administrator access, and this could all be done without affecting your husband's account.
(How to do any of that would likely be one or more separate questions.  I'm simply pointing out that the requested objectives are technically achievable, even if the typical way people may perform one or more of these actions may not be very simplistic.)
